# Re-map Array with Totals from matching inner array items

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My Document Collection Looks as below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "596e004151cc92046c28dd39"
    },
    "routes": [
      {
        "legs": [
          {
            "LegId":0,
            "end_address": "B",
            "start_address": "A",
             "price":123
          },
          {
            "LegId":1,
            "end_address": "C",
            "start_address": "B",
             "price":123

          },
          {
            "LegId":2,
            "end_address": "D",
            "start_address": "C",
             "price":120
          },
          {
            "LegId":3,
            "end_address": "E",
            "start_address": "D",
              "price":125
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": "OK",
    "Date": {
      "$date": "2017-07-18T12:34:07.781Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "596e007d51cc9231a8117607"
    },
    "routes": [
      {
        "legs": [
          {
            "LegId":0,
            "end_address": "E",
            "start_address": "F",
              "price":300
          },
          {
            "LegId":1,
            "end_address": "D",
            "start_address": "E",
              "price":200
          },
          {
            "LegId":2,
            "end_address": "C",
            "start_address": "D",
              "price":200
          },
          {
            "LegId":3,
            "end_address": "B",
            "start_address": "C",
              "price":200
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": "OK",
    "Date": {
      "$date": "2017-07-18T12:35:09.121Z"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to Project the Status,Date and also the total price of the legs between StartAddress="A and end Address="D"  (find the leg id by passing the start address and end address and use $gt and $lt on legId)

FYI: As for finding the top level document i use an ancestors field in each document to filter 2 the desired document.

Sorry If I'm confusing with the language.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, i'm trying out your suggestion with my Data, will be updating the post today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest is largely the application of [`$filter`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220120110113/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), [`$map`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220216100518/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$sum`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220318090453/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Still actually query for documents that meet the later filter conditions
  { "$match": {
    "routes": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "legs": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "start_address": { "$gte": "A" },
            "end_address": { "$lte": "D" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  // Just return the wanted array fields and the sum of the matching inner
  { "$addFields": {
    "routes": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$routes",
        "as": "r",
        "in": {
          "Status": "$$r.Status",
          "Date": "$$r.Date",
          "totalPrice": {
            "$sum": {
              "$map": {
                "input": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$r.legs",
                    "as": "l",
                    "cond": {
                      "$and": [
                        { "$gte": [ "$$l.start_address", "A" ] },
                        { "$lte": [ "$$l.end_address", "D" ] }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "as": "l",
                "in": "$$l.price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

To explain that, there are a couple of parts. First, the outer [`$map`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220216100518/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) is iterating over the outer `"routes"` array and simply returning all of those entries. If we wanted to "filter" anything here then we would similarly apply a [`$filter`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220120110113/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to the `"input"` of this [`$map`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220216100518/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), but your question does not indicate anything other than returning the `"totalPrice"`.

So the other array properties are merely named in the output, just like with "map" in any other language implementation. For the `"totalPrice"` you clearly want [`$sum`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220318090453/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), but we need to use [`$filter`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220120110113/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in order to match the array elements and then [`$map`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220216100518/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to get the specific field `"price"` to actually feed the [`$sum`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220318090453/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

The arguments to [`$filter`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220120110113/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) here are specified in the `"cond"` where you use the "logical forms" of [`$gte`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220213222206/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/) and [`$lte`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220213222206/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/) which return a boolean result as is expected of the argument and only then keep those array members. The [`$and`](https://web.archive.org/web/20211024113921/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) extends that logical condition by ensuring that both inner arguments need to return `true` in order for that to return `true`.

Comment: :O.. thanks for the detailed response. ill give this a try and get back :)